# Почему при разных условиях программы, возвращается разные значения?

Tags: javascript

```
//declare variable;
var balance = 10500;
var cameraOn = true;
var amount = steal(balance, 1250);
//function;
function steal(balance, amount) {
    cameraOn = false;
    if (amount < balance) {
        balance = balance - amount;
    }
    return amount; // amount = 1250 
}

console.log(amount); // возвращает amount = 1250
```

Если изменить на **return balance**, то то amount = 9250, почему так?

Comment: Вы возвращаете amount, который не зменяется в процессе выполнения функции. 
`var balance = 10500;
var cameraOn = true;
var newBalance = steal(balance, 1250);
function steal(balance, amountToSteal) {
    cameraOn = false;
    if (amountToSteal < balance) {
        balance = balance - amountToSteal;
    }
    return balance;
}
console.log(newBalance);`

Comment: Это я понял, меня интересует почему, значение amount будет другим, если поменять на return balance, тогда он возвращает значение глобальной переменной balance и глобальной переменной  amount!

Comment: @October потому, что в 3-й строке вы присваиваете переменной `amount` значение, которое вернет ф-ция `steal`, а в случае с `return balance`, она вернет `balance`, то есть 9250

Comment: Вангую, что вы путаете amount внутри функции и снаружи. Это две разные совершенно никак между собой не связанные переменные

Comment: @AlexeyTen Скорее всего так и есть. Поэтому я и переписал код автора на более читаемый

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var amount = steal(balance, 1250);
```

Вы присваиваете переменной `amount` значение, которое вернёт функция `steal`

В вашем примере :

```
 function steal(balance, amount) {
    cameraOn = false;
    if (amount < balance) {
        balance = balance - amount;
    }
    return amount; // amount = 1250 
}
```

функция всегда будет возвращать второй параметр, в том виде, в котором он был передан в функцию steal(balance, **1250**), а занчит конечное значение переменной `amount` всегда будет равно этому параметру.
Возможно у вас возникла путаница между переменной `amount` внутри функции и снаружи. Подробнее про области видимости переменных [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/closures)

Вот ваш отформатированный код, возможно он придаст вам некую ясность

```
  var balance = 10500;   
  var newBalance = steal(balance, 1250);

  function steal(balance, amountToSteal) { 
    if (amountToSteal < balance) {
      balance = balance - amountToSteal;
    } 
    return balance; 
  }
 console.log(newBalance);
```

Comment: параметр balance тоже стоило бы переименовать

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! на самом деле я ни чего не путал, это было сделано специально автором учебника))